# PDO: Generated binds arent working

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to set up a function to generate binds for PDO.

The binds are generated by a function and compiled into an array.

I then tried to parse the values (bind statement) through a foreach loop, but it keeps throwing Undefined Property.

The loop looks like this:

```
foreach($binds as $key => $bind){
  $stmt -> $bind;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
$stmt -> bindValue(':ID', $ID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt -> bindValue(':Name', $Name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt -> bindValue(':Test', $Test, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

But it isn't working... why?

**Error Message:**

`Notice: Undefined property: PDOStatement::$bindValue(':ID', $ID, PDO::PARAM_STR)`

(does that for all)

Comment: Show us the **exact** error message. `$stmt -> $bind;` --- it makes no sense.

Comment: Pretty sure an instance of $bind looks like "bindValue(':ID', $ID, PDO::PARAM_STR);", so he can attach it directly to the $stmt object.

Comment: @Mike Purcell: lol what? You cannot do that :-)

Comment: @zerkms: Have no idea, just what it looks like he is trying to accomplish.

Comment: @MikePurcell Yep, that's what I'm trying. Why can you not do that?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to set up a function to generate binds for PDO.

You don't need it. PDO already has such a function called execute(). So, instead of your loop just run

```
$stmt->execute($binds);
```

Comment: Then I get `Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined`. I expected the loop to work, since if I place what it outputs in directly it does work :/

Comment: Actually, just changed $binds to my $values, which outputs [key] = 'value' array. So this is perfectly secure and binds it to prevent injection?